# call component method from user submitted stringIn vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a website that simulates a terminal as a browser startpage and I'm using vue.js for my templates. E.g. the `locate` command should open a search query using duckduckgo.

Now I have a terminal component, which looks like this:

```
 export default {
  name: "terminal",
  components: {
    prompt,
    termOut
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      command: "",
      wd: "~"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onCommand: function(command) {
      console.log(`got command: ${command}`);
    },
    onCommandSubmit: function(com) {
      console.log(`got command: ${com} (submitted)`);
      let c = com.split(' ')[0];
      this[c]();
    }
  },
  locate: function (args) {
          if (args[0]) {
        window.open("https://duckduckgo.com/" + args.join(' '));
    } else {
        return("Please enter a valid search query");
    }
  }
};
```

the basic idea is that the command (which is propperly submitted by the user via the child component `prompt`) is executed if it is recognized from the terminal component. I tried doing so by accessing the function property as shown in the `onCommandSubmit` method.

The problem is that the vue component does not recognize `this[locate]` as a function of itself.

I understand that it is generally a bad idea to let the user issue commands on himself, but I don't mind to much as its just a personal project.

If there is a better way to handle the user-submitted commands I'd also be open for hints.

Comment: your locate method is not inside the methods object of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Your component needed emit a event with the parameter, then you get this value in parent component to process.

component.vue

```
<template>
  <v-btn @click="onSendToParent()" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        values: {
          name: 'my name',
          blabla: 'blablabla'
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSendToParent() {
        console.log(`✅ Emited sendToParent:`, this.values) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        this.$emit('sendToParent', this.values)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

parent.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  {{ childData }}
  <!-- @sendToParent is the name of your emiter, you can use change, update, and any thing you want. -->
  <my-component @sendToParent="useChildData" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from 'component'
  export default {
    components: {
      MyComponent
    },
    data() {
      return {
        childData: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      useChildData(event) {
        console.log(`✅ get data Emited from childComponent:`, event) // eslint-disable-line no-console
        this.childData = event
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```